# Proving irregularity of $\{a^nb^k \mid n > k \text{ or } n \neq k-1\}$

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I need help with proving the following language is not regular:
$$
L = \{ a^n b^k \mid n > k \} \cup \{ a^n b^k \mid n \neq k-1 \}
$$
My usual methods using pumping lemma are not getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n > k$ then $n \neq k-1$ (since $k-1 \not> k$), so your language is really $L = \{ a^n b^k \mid n \neq k-1 \}$. If $L$ were regular then so would be the following language $a(a^*b^* \setminus L) \cup \{\epsilon\} = \{ a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0 \}$, which is known not to be regular.

Comment: The definition of says n>k or n!=(k-1). Why wouldn't we include the cases where n<(k-1)?

Comment: ignore the previous question, but can you tell me how to go from reduced language to regular expression you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: After you decide that L reduced to L=$ \{a^nb^k | n \neq k-1\}$, you decided that this language is the same as a^nb^n.

Comment: Definitely not. I looked at $a(a^*b^*\setminus L) \cup \{\epsilon\}$.

Comment: So, you are trying to manipulate L to go to a known non-regular language which is $a^nb^n$. And the operations you used to manipulate L are the kind of operations that regular languages are closed under. If L was regular, the resulting language must have been regular. Is this correct?  What "\" stand for? Thanks.

Comment: That’s correct. The backslash denotes set difference.